# How to force authentication over HTTPS

Tags: http, authentication, https, pci-compliance

During our last PCI scan, we received these 2 fail points: "Basic Authentication over HTTP" and "Web Page Transmits Login Credentials Without Encryption." Both were on Port 2077.

Though our Wordpress website has an SSL, it seems as if logging in is still authenticating over HTTP. How do I get the website to use SSL for authentication?

Comment: what's the webserver that you're using? are you hosting directly on wordpress or using your own install?